# ZSH search for function definition

Tags: shell, zsh

Is there a mechanism for getting a function definition from console without grepping manually files ?

I search for a way to find fast a definition of known function name.

For example I want to know where "_kill" autocompletion function is defined.

In ruby with the use of pry I can get something like this:

> show-method find
>
> From: app/models/search/object.rb @ line 2:
>
> Number of lines: 7

```
def self.find(conditions = {}, options = {})
  type = extract_object_type
  raise 'do not call Search::Object directly' if type == 'Object'
  search_logic = "Search::#{type.camelize}Logic".constantize.new(conditions, options)
  search_logic.process!
  search_logic.execute
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For zsh, try `whence -f` or `type -f`. For example:

```
myhost% whence -f _kill
_kill () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
```

Comment: is there a way to find where this function was defined ? ie.. the actual file ?

Answer (score 5):

For me following works:

```
$ autoload +X _kill # important step
$ whence -v _kill
_kill is a shell function from /usr/share/zsh/5.2/functions/_kill
```

[Zsh Documentation – 9.1 Autoloading Functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Autoloading-Functions)

> To load the definition of an autoloaded function myfunc without executing 
>    myfunc, use:
>
> `autoload +X myfunc`

After `autoload +X` you can also see the actual function with `whence -f`

```
$ whence -f _kill
_kill () {
    local curcontext="$curcontext" line state ret=1
    typeset -A opt_args
    _arguments -C '(-s -l 1)-n[specify signal number]:signal number' '(-n -l 1)-s[specify signal name]:signal:_signals -s' '(-n -s)-l[list signal names or numbers of specified signals]:*:signal:_signals' '(-n -s -l)1::signal:_signals -p -s' '*:processes:->processes' && ret=0
    if [[ -n "$state" ]]
    then
        local pgrp='process-groups:: _wanted '
        [[ -n "$opt_args[(i)-[ns]]${${(@)line:#--}}" && -prefix - ]] && pgrp+='-x '
        pgrp+="process-groups expl 'process-group' compadd - 0"
        _alternative 'processes:: _pids' 'jobs:: _jobs -t' $pgrp && ret=0
    fi
    return ret
}
```

Comment: Some may find the equivalent built-ins `type _kill` and `functions _kill` easier to remember

Comment: This is great! Can I do this for aliases too, somehow?